Copying a graph from Excel to Word as editable graph with VBA
Good day!
I have a docx file with placeholders and I'd like to replace them with a graph coming from an Excel file. I would like the graph in word to be editable (not just an image). Is it possible? I tried to use a similar approach to this one:
wdDoc.Content.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

with
rng.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

But I get a generic error at that line (Run-time error '5097': Word has encountered a problem)
This is my macro so far:
Sub ReplaceGraphPlaceholdersWithImages(doc As Document, xlBook As Object)
Dim rng As Range
Dim chartTitle As String
Dim chartName As String
Dim ws As Object
Dim ch As Object
Dim found As Boolean
Dim msgWidth As Integer

msgWidth = 60 ' Set message width

' Initialize the placeholders string
Set rng = doc.Content
found = False

' Loop through all charts in each worksheet and replace placeholders
For Each ws In xlBook.Worksheets
    For Each ch In ws.ChartObjects
        chartTitle = ch.Chart.chartTitle.Text
        chartName = Replace(LCase(chartTitle), " ", "_")
        
        ' Search for the placeholder in the Word document
        With rng.Find
            .Text = "${graph_" & chartName & "}"
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop

            Do While .Execute
                ' Copy the chart as a picture to the clipboard
                ch.Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

                ' Delete the placeholder text
                rng.Text = ""

                ' Paste the chart as an inline image
                rng.Paste

                ' Convert the pasted shape to an inline shape for inline positioning
                If doc.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
                    Set rng = doc.InlineShapes(doc.InlineShapes.Count).Range
                End If

                ' Reset range to continue searching through the whole document
                Set rng = doc.Content
                found = True
            Loop
        End With
    Next ch
Next ws


ch.Chart.CopyPicture only copies an image of the chart, so pasting as OLE aster that isn't going to work.  "i keep getting errors" doesn't tell us much about what actually happens when you run your code.

@TimWilliams, it's a generic error. But I added it to the question, thanks.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.pasteandformat and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrecoverytype
